# how to create tfileoutputdelimited with file_name_sysdate as the filename for a particular session run and append data

Tags: java, talend

I have  a tfileoutputdelimited component that has filename and i want to append the sysdate to the variable after every session run like FILENAME_20210427010624 and append processed data to the csv file contents.

How can i do this in talend?

flow like this:
`tmap->textractdelimitedfields->tfileoutputdelimited`

Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

In your tfileoutputdelimited  name just type this :

`"Your Repository "+"FILENAME_"+TalendDate.getDate("YYYYMMdd")+".csv"`

Just type your pattern ..